# Find functions from data points

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I have this correlation

```
i       0   1      2    3      4    5      6    7
f(i)    0   2.5    0    2.5    5    7.5    5    7.5
g(i)    0   2.5    5    7.5    0    2.5    5    7.5
```

Is it possible to find a function for $f(i)$ and $g(i)$ using basic mathematical operations?

How do you normally find such functions? I would have used linear regression, but I guess I have to use the modulo operator, so it is not possible.

I have found this database https://oeis.org/, which stores a lot of integer sequences, but I am afraid it is not useful since my correlations are not integers.

## Edit

I have found $g(i) = i \, \% \, 4 \cdot 2.5$ by trial and error, but I cannot find $f(i)$.

Comment: what kind of functions are you looking for? At any rate you can use Lagrange polynomials

Answer (score 1):

A simple transformation 
$f_b(i)=0.4\cdot f(i)$,
$g_b(i)=0.4\cdot g(i)$
converts data points to integers
and representation of $f_b(i),g_b(i)$ and $i$
in binary format 
helps to get the answer easily:

```
i   f(i)   g(i)   0.4*f(i)  0.4*g(i)   f_b(i)   g_b(i)   i_b   
0   0         0      0         0          00      00      000   
1   2.5     2.5      1         1          01      01      001   
2   0         5      0         2          00      10      010   
3   2.5     7.5      1         3          01      11      011   
4   5         0      2         0          10      00      100   
5   7.5     2.5      3         1          11      01      101   
6   5         5      2         2          10      10      110   
7   7.5     7.5      3         3          11      11      111
```

Considering data bit columns separately,
it is clear, that $0$-bit of $f_b(i)$ is just $i\%2$.

The other bit columns also show a simple pattern.

Then one of possible expressions for $f_b$ is

\begin{align}
f_b(i)&=i\%2+(i-(i\%4))/2
\\
f(i)&=f_b(i)\cdot 2.5
\end{align}

Comment: I don't quite understand it, because if I take $f_b(5) = 5\%2+(5-(5\%4)/2) = 5.5$ but I wanted $f(5) = 7.5$?

Comment: @mortensen: It should read  i%2+(i−(i%4))/2, typo fixed.

Comment: I still don't understand it because $f_b(5) = 5\%2+(5−(5\%4))/2 = 3$. So I also have to divide it by $0.4$?

Comment: @mortensen: yes, $f_b(5)=3$, $f(5)=f_b(5)*2.5=7.5$